# IOS/Facebook: Deprecation of App Invite Workaround

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-like, facebook-app-invites

It appears that as of February 5, 2018, [Facebook no longer supports app invite](https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2017/11/07/changes-developer-offerings/).  Does this mean that it is now impossible for a Facebook user to invite a group of friends or even one friend to download an IOS app? In other words, are there no workarounds to this?  I guess the user can still post a download link to the Timeline, but I'm wondering if there is any way for a FB user or IOS app to specifically invite specific friends to download app whether through a message, notification or other means.

Thanks for any confirmation/clarification or other suggestions.